# which one is larger? 8 factorial to the power of 1/8 or 9 factorial to the power of 1/9

Tags: arithmetic

Which one is larger?

8 factorial to the power of 1/8 or 9 factorial to the power of 1/9. Show your work without calculator.

Comment: As the exercise requires: "Show your work." :-)

Comment: sry 4 replying late,actly,at first, ttl have no clue working on this question. @trancelocation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint:* Compare $(8!)^9=(8!)(8!)^8$ and $(9!)^8=9^8(8!)^8$.

Comment: thx! since 8! is less than 9^8, (8!)^9 is less than (9!)^8, thus both them to the power of 1/72 then we have 8 factorial to the power of 1/8 is less than 9 factorial to the power of 1/9.

Answer (score 0):

Define the function $f(x) = x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ and calculate its derivative. You should get $f'(x)=-x^{\frac{1}{x}-2}(ln(x)-1)$. You see that that $\forall x > e: f'(x) < 0$ since $ln(e)=1$. Thus, the function $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing function for $x>e \approx 2.718$. Hence, $f(8) > f(9)$.

Comment: You need $f(x)=(x!)^{1/x}$. And probably use $\Gamma$ instead of factorial.

Comment: True, I missed the factorial part. It's still possible but your solution seems more elegant, faster and easier.